# Query on date range with mongo

Tags: mongodb

My document looks like:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52ee0844177c86dc1d000001"),
        "profile" : {
                "displayName" : "Sydney",
        },
        "todos" : [
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-02-02T21:47:13.064Z"),
                        "value" : "#first in the #middle also but twice #middle and the #end",
                        "tags" : [
                                "#first",
                                "#middle",
                                "#end"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-02-05T21:20:30.904Z"),
                        "value" : "Find mongo query #mongo #work",
                        "tags" : [
                                "#mongo",
                                "#work"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to query the todo for a date range:

```
> var start = new Date()
> var end = new Date()
> start.setDate(start.getDate() - 2)
1391544140700
> start
ISODate("2014-02-04T20:02:20.700Z")
> end
ISODate("2014-02-06T20:02:25.828Z")
>db.users.find({todos: {$elemMatch: {date: { $gte: start, $lt: end }}}}, {'todos':1}).pretty()
```

but the query still returns the two records. I was expecting to get only the last one.

Comment: I use the following answer to fix the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12241733/1259510

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> If multiple elements match the $elemMatch condition, the operator
>   returns the **first** matching element in the array.

This is by design (*limitation*) and there is no other operator that would return only the matching elements. One approach is to use the aggregation framework to filter the returned elements of the array:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$match: {todos: {$elemMatch: {date: { $gte: start, $lt: end }} } }},
    {$unwind: "$todos"},
    {$match:{"todos.date": { $gte: start, $lt: end } }},
    {$group: { _id: { _id: "$_id", profile: "$profile" }, todos: {$push: "$todos" } } },
    {$project: {_id: "$_id._id", profile: "$_id.profile", todos: 1 } }
])
```

If only one field is required use the [positional](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in combination with $elemMatch to return only the item that matched as it would not make much sense to restate the $elemMatch in the projection.

```
{todos: {$elemMatch: {date: { $gte: start, $lt: end }}}}, {"todos.$": 1}
```

Comment: I don't want the first, I want all items that matches. Using aggregate works

Comment: Using aggregate only will work in that case. Your example should be clearer to this point. As it stands you only have two documents. I believe you have answered your own question.